# Como achar um Select sem campo de ID ou NAME

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

possuo um projeto de teste onde tenho que realizar alguns inserts no form e validar se está tudo fluindo bem, porém o Dev que criou o form não colocou o select da seguinte forma:

```
<select id="" name="">
```

Ele apenas criou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra achar esse Select sendo que o class dele é padrão Bootstrap (outros elementos do FORM possui a mesma class...

Estou usando o Selenium com Python para tal, alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Daria para fazer baseando-se na classe, porém se tiver mais de um select com mesma classe, retornaria um array de selects. Desta forma, você teria que colocar a posição do item no array. =D

Comment: @Viana não entendi muito bom poderia ser um pouco mais claro?

Answer (score 0):

Caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, segue a solução que eu achei:

```
data.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='form-control']/option[text()='" + x + "']").click()
```